# Migrate bootstrap theme 3 to 4 programmatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing some housekeeping on a project I haven't touched for a couple of years.

Among the different changes, I would like to migrate from bootstrap 3 to 4.

This rails app is using a bootstrap 3 theme that my friends who are using the website like a lot. I built some react components on top of it as well.

There is any programmatic way to migrate js and css files from bootstrap 3 to 4?

Several rules have changed but before going for a full restyling I was wondering if there was some script or cli to perform all the required substitutions on my assets.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to update your app/theme or how to replace the library files?

Comment: How to update the theme. I supposed that there are some tools to migrate themes based on the replacement of the breaking change. I may leverage on these scripts to update my customizations as well